# How to extra panel below another

Tags: swing, user-interface, panel, layout-manager, border-layout

add(Panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(Panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

I know one way to do it is like above. But the way I want to layout the panels is so that both are set on North, but Panel2 is below the Panel1. How will I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, don't use BorderLayout, but use some other layout manager instead, like GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Put the panel within a panel... within your top-level component (which might also be a panel). Three levels of layout managers.